# Coin flip games with 50% and 50% probability

Tags: java, python

So I am trying to generate coin flip game code.

So far I've written code in python like this(stuck in generating function in 50% probability)

```
import random

coin = random.randint(0, 1)

print(coin)
if coin == 1:
    print("front")
else:
    print("back")
```

I've started learning python since last week! I'm in need of help
Also if anyone can help me in solving this problem by Java too?

Comment: Your code works fine. What else do you want your code to do?

Comment: for example i'd like to execute this process in 10 times(filipping coin 10 times), and trying to get 50% probability of front and back (head&tail).

Comment: check the answer I had. you can define desire probability by probabilities = [0.5, 0.5]. change it to see the result too

Comment: There’s also `java.util.Random.nextBoolean()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have 10 time with given probabilities (I do for 50% 50%)

```
import numpy as np
import collections
elements = [1, 0]
probabilities = [0.5, 0.5]
a=np.random.choice(elements, 10, p=probabilities)
```

Result would be like:
`[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]`

you can count number of 0 and 1 by below code:

`collections.Counter(a)`

result of counting is: `Counter({1: 7, 0: 3})`

putting all in one:

```
import numpy as np
import collections
elements = [1, 0]
probabilities = [0.5, 0.5]
a=np.random.choice(elements, 10, p=probabilities)
print(a)
count=collections.Counter(a)
print(count)
```

Comment: I don't think he will understand the code. he just began coding last week.

Comment: I tried to explain and simplify it, by the way if the code isn't clear let me know @coding_n00b

Comment: I'm trying to generate result by Counter({0: 5 1: 5}). Could you explain how "count=collections.Counter(a)" this logic of this code works? @Mohsen

Comment: `count=collections.Counter(a)` give you the count of any value in array (a). `Counter({0: 5 1: 5})` may happen and may not because it is probability. the probability for each value defined here: `probabilities = [0.5, 0.5]`. If you change it to let say  `[0.01, 0.99]` it is more probable that 1 happen than 0.
In `elements = [1, 0]` you define which values happen, then in `probabilities = [0.5, 0.5]` you define what is each value probability, and finally in  `np.random.choice(elements, 10, p=probabilities)` you will have 10 value from elements with given probability.
hope to be useful

Answer (score 1):

Then you need some way to store the result of the coin flip.

```
import random

flip_count = 12
heads = 0
tails = 0
for i in range(flip_count):
    coin = random.randint(0,1)
    if coin == 1:
        heads = heads + 1
    else:
        tails = tails + 1

print("The number of heads is: "+str(heads))
print("The number of tails is: "+str(tails))
```